# How can I stdout a variable which is included from another yml file in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have included a variable from a different Ansible `.yml` file. How do I print that variable to `STDOUT` in my playbook?

Here is an example playbook to show what I am trying to achieve:

```
---
- hosts: host1
  var_files: configure.yml

tasks: 
  - name: Print to stdout
    action: {{build}}.stdout
```

**build is the variable which is included from another yml file**

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the `debug` module, add this as a "task":

```
  - debug: var={{build}}.stdout
```

I'm wondering whether braces are needed you've shown them, but I can't tell without more context. If this doesn't give what you expect, try without the braces. Try without the `.stdout` as well, the information shown can be quite educational.

Comment: braces aren't needed.